# NEST - IndexMany doesn't index my objects

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I've used NEST for elasticsearch for a while now and up until now I've used the regular ElasticSearchClient.Index(...) function, but now I want to index many items in a bulk operation.

I found the IndexMany(...) function, but I must do something wrong because nothing is added to the elastic search database as it does with the regular Index(...) function?

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many 'things' are you trying to index at the same time? What is the size? There is a size limit of approximately 100MB which is enforced by the HTTP content length limit.

Comment: For my test I'm only using 2 items and none of them is ending up in my index. I know about the limit :) And I doesn't get any error from the IndexMany(...) function either :/

Comment: What does the `.DebugInformation` property on the response say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I had to specifiy the index name in the call to IndexMany

```
 var res = ElasticClient.CreateIndex("pages", i => i.Mappings(m => m.Map<ESPageViewModel>(mm => mm.AutoMap())));

                var page = new ESPageViewModel
                {
                    Id = dbPage.Id,
                    PageId = dbPage.PageId,
                    Name = dbPage.Name,
                    Options = pageTags,
                    CustomerCategoryId = saveTagOptions.CustomerCategoryId,
                    Link = dbPage.Link,
                    Price = dbPage.Price
                };

                var pages = new List<ESPageViewModel>() { page };

                var res2 = ElasticClient.IndexManyAsync<ESPageViewModel>(pages, "pages");
```

This works as expected. Guess I could specify a default index name in the configuration to avoid specifying the index for the IndexMany call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# you should create a list of objects that you want to insert then call the IndexMany function.

Example :

```
List<Business> businessList = new List<Business>();

#region Fill the business list
............................... 
#endregion

if (businessList.Count == 1000) // the size of the bulk.
{
     EsClient.IndexMany<Business>(businessList, IndexName);

     businessList.Clear();
}
```

And in the end check again

```
if (businessList.Count > 0)
{
    EsClient.IndexMany<Business>(businessList, IndexName);
 }
```